# You have an error in your SQL syntax near ':table_templates_boxes_to_pages

Tags: mysql

Hii i am trying to display data which is present in :table_templates_boxes but not present in :table_templates_boxes_to_pages but i am getting error. Plesrs help me out

Here is my code

```
SELECT 
  tb.id,
  tb.code 
FROM
  mxp_templates_boxes tb,
  mxp_templates_boxes_to_pages tbtp 
WHERE templates_id = 3 
  AND tb.id NOT IN 
  (SELECT 
    templates_boxes_id 
  FROM
    :table_templates_boxes_to_pages) 
ORDER BY tbtp.sort_order
```

Comment: table name can't start with `:`.

Comment: please post the exact error u get. and i think it may be this: `FROM
    :table_` remove the ` : `

Comment: Are those supposed to be table names, or Ruby :symbols, or PHP PDO params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 1**:

> *i want only id of `mxp_templates_boxes` which are not present in `mxp_templates_boxes_to_pages` but instead it's returning all id's of `mxp_templates_boxes`*

Try this:

```
SELECT tb.id, tb.code 
  FROM mxp_templates_boxes tb
 WHERE tb.templates_id = 3 
   AND tb.id NOT IN ( select distinct templates_boxes_id 
                      from mxp_templates_boxes_to_pages )
```

**Sample** @ [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dab07/4)

---

**Original answer**:

> *data which is present in `table_templates_boxes` but not present in `table_templates_boxes_to_pages`*

You can directly use table alias that is already defined.

```
SELECT 
  tb.id,
  tb.code 
FROM
  mxp_templates_boxes tb,
  mxp_templates_boxes_to_pages tbtp 
WHERE templates_id = 3 
  AND tb.id NOT IN ( tbtp.templates_boxes_id )
ORDER BY tbtp.sort_order
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and it worked but i want only id of mxp_templates_boxes which are not present in mxp_templates_boxes_to_pages but instead it's returning all id's of mxp_templates_boxes.